# Knex.js Migrations move/copy existing data

Tags: knex.js

Is it possible to modify existing data in the database using Knex.js migrations?

For example, if I have an existing column 'name' in my database and I want to split it up into two columns 'first_name' and 'last_name', is it possible to do this with migrations?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Yep

Something like this should do:

```
exports.up = function (knex) {
  return knex.schema.table('your_table', (table) => {
    table.string('first_name');
    table.string('last_name');
  }).then(() => {
    return knex('your_table').update({
      // this requires that each name are in form 'fistname lastname'
      // if you need to do more complex transformation regexp_split_to_array migth help
      first_name: knex.raw(`split_part(??, ' ', 1)`, ['name']),
      last_name: knex.raw(`split_part(??, ' ', 2)`, ['name'])
    });
  }).then(function () {
     // drop original column, but I would suggest leaving it in
     // to be able to verify values in new columns
  });
};

exports.down = function () {};
```